# psql does not read .pgpass

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am able to login to PostgreSQL server by providing username, hostname and database name:

```
psql -U led -h 127.0.0.1 led
psql (9.2.23)
Type "help" for help.

led=>
```

I have this .pgpass file:

```
cat .pgpass 
127.0.0.1:5432:led:led:password
```

psql does not work. It seems it is failing to read .pgpass:

```
psql 
psql: FATAL:  role "vagrant" does not exist
```

As you can see, psql tries to logon as user "vagrant": the OS shell user. But I want to logon as user "led".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.pgpass` file provides password details for a particular user on a particular host/port/database (or pattern). It can contain multiple lines because you might connect to multiple hosts as multiple users.

You still need to set connection details, it then uses those to look up your password.

If you just want a "default" connection that is different than your system username and not local then you could do either by defining an `alias` or setting [environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html). I frequently have a settings file at the top of a project that I `source` to set connection details for my test database.

Edit: some background information on setting up command aliases

- http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-useful-bash-aliases-and-functions

Comment: Could you describe more about the `alias`?

Comment: I assumed .pgpass is used to lookup username and hostname too like .my.cnf. It's only the password!

Comment: Links about aliases added to bottom of answer